# How to properly delete column in datagrid by click cell inside datagird?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here is [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/datatable-material-demo-with-remove-column-icon-forked-cbjfm?file=/demo.js) link.  If the remove One column button is clicked , then I would pass a different column's value. Thus I remove the full name column from Datagrid. Now I would like to achieve the same goal by clicking the cell inside dataged. So I add a props in the Datagrid, if the cell we click is fullname , then I would update datagrid's columns state. However,  I got Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valueFormatter').

```
  const onCellClick = (cell) => {
    console.log(cell);
    if (cell.field === "fullName") {
      console.log("?????");
      //remove last column
      // copy directly from above onClick method
      setColumns([
        { field: "id", headerName: "ID", width: 70 },
        { field: "firstName", headerName: "First name", width: 130 },
        { field: "lastName", headerName: "Last name", width: 130 },
        {
          field: "age",
          headerName: "Age",
          type: "number",
          width: 90
        }
      ]);
    }
  };
```